# d3.quantile seems to be calculating Q1 incorrectly

Tags: d3.js, statistics, quantile

I'm giving a sorted array of 24 numbers to `d3.quantile` and asking it to calculate the first quartile value.  Since the array can be split evenly into four groups of 6 values, my assumption was that the result would be the mean of arr[5] and arr[6], but that's not what I got.

```
var arr = [89.7, 93.2, 94, 94.3, 94.5, 95.4, 95.9, 96.1, 96.4, 96.5, 96.9, 96.9, 97.3, 97.6, 97.6, 97.6, 97.8, 98.3, 98.3, 98.4, 98.5, 98.5, 98.6, 98.6];
var myAssumption = (arr[5] + arr[6]) / 2;   // 95.65
var d3Result = d3.quantile(arr, 0.25);      // 95.775
```

Does the d3 quantile function use some more complex algorithm?  [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample) lists several options, but I'm not sure which is being used (or why one algorithm is preferable to another).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is not incorrect, that's the expected value.

If you look at that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample) page you linked, you'll see "R-7" in the *type* column (it's written *"R-7, Excel, SciPy-(1,1), Maple-6"*). That's the algorithm used by `d3.quantile()` function.

Have a look at the source code of `d3.quantile()`:

```
export default function(values, p, valueof) {
    if (valueof == null) valueof = number;
    if (!(n = values.length)) return;
    if ((p = +p) <= 0 || n < 2) return +valueof(values[0], 0, values);
    if (p >= 1) return +valueof(values[n - 1], n - 1, values);
    var n,
        i = (n - 1) * p,
        i0 = Math.floor(i),
        value0 = +valueof(values[i0], i0, values),
        value1 = +valueof(values[i0 + 1], i0 + 1, values);
    return value0 + (value1 - value0) * (i - i0);
}
```

So, in your case, we'll have:

```
i = (24 - 1) * 0.25
//   ^--- the length of the array
```

Which gives us `5.75` (and `5` as `Math.floor(i)`).

Then the returned value (which is `value0 + (value1 - value0) * (i - i0)` in the function) will be:

```
95.4 + (95.9 - 95.4) * (5.75 - 5)
```

And that gives us the result you're seeing:

```
95.775
```

Here is the running demo:

```js
var arr = [89.7, 93.2, 94, 94.3, 94.5, 95.4, 95.9, 96.1, 96.4, 96.5, 96.9, 96.9, 97.3, 97.6, 97.6, 97.6, 97.8, 98.3, 98.3, 98.4, 98.5, 98.5, 98.6, 98.6];
var d3Result = d3.quantile(arr, 0.25);
console.log(d3Result)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```